# Grab screen pixel data "behind" the Windows 10 magnifier tool

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, screen-capture, magnification-api

I was wondering if it would be possible to capture the whole view of the screen while the windows magnifier tool is running in fullscreen mode. Essentially, what I am looking for is while I'm looking with my eyes at a certain point on the screen, and only that certain point of the screen is shown on my monitor, I want to have the ability to printscreen the entirety of the original screen without closing out of magnifier. No clue how to word it better and clearer than that. I know it's possible to get screen pixels info through the `Graphics` class like so:

```
this.graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
this.graphics.CopyFromScreen(pictureBoxPoint.X, pictureBoxPoint.Y, 0, 0, size);
```

But this does not exclude the magnifier's influence on the screen, and only grabs it as it's seen by the user. What I would ideally like to be able to do is grab the entirety of the screen as it's supposed to be seen if the magnifier tool wasn't zooming in only on one part, if that makes sense. The *entire* screenspace even if only *part* is visible.

I had a quick look at the [Magnification API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/magapi/magapi-intro#selective-magnification) docs page, but I have no idea if that is actually where I should be looking. Is there something else I can do? I'd appreciate it if someone pointed me in the right direction because I seem to be going in circles.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the github project [karna-magnification](https://github.com/perevoznyk/karna-magnification), this will allow you to make a windows form object into the view portal and magnify anything under the cursor.  To capture the magnification, you just need to capture the contents of the form.
Once you reference the github project, in the constructor for the form you want to use as the magnifier view panel, Add

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Magnifier mg = new Magnifier(this);
        }
    }
}
```

from there add code to use the graphics context of the form to capture the image.  That part I will leave to you.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, though. I would like to capture an image of the unmagnified screen (forego the magnification layer) ***while*** I'm magnifying it for my personal use with the WIndows 10 magnifier tool or whatever else, if that makes sense. How to take a picture of the entire screenspace when the screen shows only the magnified part, essentially.